# react-chartjs-2 hiding axis label

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm trying to hide yAxis labels. I tried `display: false` property, but that didn't work.
My code below:

```
export const options = {
  responsive: true,
  interaction: { includeInvisible: true, intersect: false },
  tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
    displayColors: false,
    multiKeyBackground: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
  },
  scale: {
    y1: {
      min: 0,
      ticks: {
        count: 5,
      },
      grid: { borderDash: [3], color: "rgb(126,126,126)", tickLength: 0 },
    },
    y2: {
      display: false,
      position: "right",
      max: Math.max(...BTCPrices.map((el) => el.Volume)) * 10,
      ticks: {
        count: 5,
      },
    },
    x: {
      ticks: {},
    },
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
  },
};
```

here's the image describing the problem:
[image]
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your config is not getting picked up, you putted your scale config in the `options.scale` namespace white it needs to be configured in the `options.scales` so you need to add an extra `s` at the end

Comment: That's why I love typescript. You can never make such a mistake ever if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I manage to get rid of the labels, I think in your case instead of **Y** its gonna be **y2**

```
  y: {
      ticks: {
        display: false, //this will remove only the label
      },
    },
```